# Have 'make' not output "redirecting incorrect #include" warnings during CC/GCC build?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, gnu-make, cc

Is there any flag to get *'make'* to **not** output *"redirecting incorrect #include"* messages during a CC/GCC building?

I get that *--disable-warnings-as-errors* might do, but is there a more specific one?

Example output that's wanted to be silenced:

```
In file included from ./src/or/or.h:31:0,
                 from src/test/test_routerlist.c:12:
/usr/include/sys/fcntl.h:1:2: warning: #warning redirecting incorrect #include <sys/fcntl.h> to <fcntl.h> [-Wcpp]
 #warning redirecting incorrect #include <sys/fcntl.h> to <fcntl.h>
```

Comment: Seems like you're treating the symptoms, not the disease.  Can you change the code to include the correct header?

Comment: @StephenNewell not lightly, no. The case is of Tor getting built on Alpine linux. _(And it's just a minor nuisance/eye-sore, really. So not really worth the effort, if it can't be done easy)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce (my copy of `sys/fcntl.h` is `#include <fcntl.h>`), but try adding `-Wno-cpp` to your cflags.  From `man gcc`:

```
   -Wno-cpp
       (C, Objective-C, C++, Objective-C++ and Fortran only)

       Suppress warning messages emitted by "#warning" directives.
```

In general, the option that triggered the warning is printed along with the warning (`-Wcpp` for you).  You can disable specific warnings with the `-Wno-<warning>` flag.

Comment: Thanks! That did the works for now!. And i will also look into how to specify specific warnings, so thanks for that tip as well. cheers.